# How to share and project Powerpoint presentation with ARD

Tags: remote-desktop, ms-office

I would like to present a Powerpoint 2011 presentation in a classroom with ~20 student machines equipped with Apple Remote Desktop 3.5.1.  There is also a projector and small screen in front.  I have two closely-related questions:

1. When I project the presentation, I can get the presenter view on the instructor machine, which is great, but, when I share my desktop, students see the presenter view, not the full-screen slide show being projected.  Is there a way to choose which of my displays to share?
2. Is Share Screen even the right feature to use?  In the Apple forum, [users recommended creating a Powerpoint show and pushing that to user machines](https://discussions.apple.com/message/9014639#9014639), rather than using Screen Share; however, I would like to control the pace of the slides (because of animations, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the first query - When the students connect they should see both of your displays and then be able to select Display 1 or Display 2 for a closer look at either one. These options appear (or not) depending on the display arrangement setup under Displays in System Preferences.

The bottom line is, ARD is *not* really suited to this task. There is a piece of software that does *exactly* what you're after, but it does cost. It's called **[LANSchool](http://www.lanschool.com/)**.

The killer LANSchool feature that you're looking for is - '[**Show Teacher's Screen**](http://www.lanschool.com/support/tutorials/show-teacher)'. This overlays your screen onto a selection of student machines. There's a 30 day trial available, I highly recommend you try it out!

Comment: thanks for the tip and for the pointer to LANSchool.  It also offers the ability to poll students, which is something I'd been wishing for.

Comment: No worries dude. If this satisfies your needs please consider accepting my answer :)

Comment: I will after I get a chance to try it out.  FYI, not a dude.

Comment: Heheh. Rule 37 ;)

Comment: Just glad you didn't cite Rule 34.  ;-)

Comment: I'm in the lab now.  I'm projecting with non-mirrored displays and sharing my screen with a student computer, which shows both displays.  I don't see a way to let a student choose between them.

Answer (score 0):

The built in Lion screen sharing (and older OS) is VNC technology, and on a local network there is no reason why you can't have 5 to 10 macs mirroring the main machine especially if it has a recent CPU and smallish screen (less than 24 inches).

Apple Remote Desktop is nice, and can assist with lowering the quality of the screen / bandwidth.

Do look into Apple TV and iOS using AirPlay as it's generally far superior and works well with remotes, other iOS devices and can integrate presenter notes using the keynote software and keynote remote. You will need some hardware to get from HDMI to older projectors, but the increase in agility makes it superior and usually worth the expense for a regular setting where you will be presenting.